# Concatenate pandas Dataframe via groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a pandas DataFrame with columns 'x', 'y', 'z'
However a lot of the x and y values are redundant. I want to take all rows that have the same x and y values and sum the third column, returning a smaller DataFrame. 
So given

```
         x     y         z
0       1      2         1
1       1      2         5
2       1      2         0
3       1      3         0
4       2      6         1
```

it would return:

```
        x      y         z
0       1      2         6
1       1      3         0
2       2      6         1
```

I've tried

```
df = df.groupby(['x', 'y'])['z'].sum
```

but I'm not sure how to work with grouped objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very close as-is; you just need to call `.sum()` and then reset the index:

```
>>> df.groupby(['x', 'y'])['z'].sum().reset_index()
   x  y  z
0  1  2  6
1  1  3  0
2  2  6  1
```

There is also a parameter to `groupby()` that handles that:

```
>>> df.groupby(['x', 'y'], as_index=False)['z'].sum()
   x  y  z
0  1  2  6
1  1  3  0
2  2  6  1
```

In your question, you have `df.groupby(['x', 'y'])['z'].sum` without parentheses.  This simply references the *method* `.sum` as a Python object, without calling it.

```
>>> type(df.groupby(['x', 'y'])['z'].sum)
method

>>> callable(df.groupby(['x', 'y'])['z'].sum)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option without using `groupby` syntax is to use the indexes and summing on index levels like this:

```
df.set_index(['x','y']).sum(level=[0,1]).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   x  y  z
0  1  2  6
1  1  3  0
2  2  6  1
```